# add number of answers by author in close queue

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

When working that close Queue I sometimes encounter a comment below the question from the OP 
stating that "it works now" or "I solved it" or something the like.

If the question is otherwise valid and I want to know if I should close it because its "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" then I have to open the Question and go check if the OP posted an answer himself.

If yes: Then its a valid question and doesn't need closing.
If not then I close it.

This could be easier if there were an information about how many of the answers are from the OP next to the amount of answers this Question has overall.

Comment: Even if the OP has posted an answer, the question may still need closing as “too local”.    Unless someone else with the same problem has a reasonable likelihood of finding the question, e.g. well defined error message they could search for.

Comment: @IanRingrose As I said, if it is otherwise valid. Of course if the problem described is most likely to by a typo or something then I have to check anyway. Maybe altering this to display the answer along with the question would be better?